# ViewPager fragmentstatepageadapter getItem isn't passing correct position

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have created a viewpager layout, a class that extends FragmentActivity and a fragment. What I want is that each fragment get's passed in what position it is within the viewpager. So first viewpager is created getting the argument 0, second getting 1 etc. Then if I scroll one way or another these numbers remain a true count.

The problem is the first time a fragment is created, it seems to be created twice so the position passed is 0 then 1. However I can't scroll back but I know for sure the class is being called twice. Now as I scroll forward the position increases incrementally by one. However if I scroll back it drops immediately to three on just one page back, then continues to drop past the 1 to 0 so now I can finally see my layout for 0.

I have this:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        PracticeFragment fragment = new PracticeFragment();
        getAll.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(getAll);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberofQ;
    }
}
```

It first of all runs getItem twice before even going to my fragment class so that the position is 0 then 1. Then when it gets to my fragment class it makes a layout fine, I scroll through a few (3 or 4) new pages and it adds one to the position each time then when I scroll back it says it is zero or two then the numbers continue to be just as sporadic. Finally suddenly when I scroll back to the beginning the position is again 0 so my fragment for position 0 is suddenly displayed.

I don't understand what's happening, so I'm wondering what the mistake is?

public class PracticeFragment extends Fragment {

```
TextView question, explain;
private ScrollView sv;
private boolean starActionBar;
private final static int version = Consts.SDKversion;

ArrayList<RadioButton> rbArray;
ArrayList<LinearLayout> lArray;
ArrayList<ImageView> ivArray;


int iRow;

SQLite info;
private String correctAnswer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    info = new SQLite(getActivity());
    starActionBar = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            getActivity()).getBoolean("star", true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    for (RadioButton r : rbArray) {
        if (r.isChecked()) {
            r.performClick();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_pm_fragment, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    lArray = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    rbArray = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    ivArray = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    lArray.add((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PM_LinLay0));
    lArray.add((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PM_LinLay1));
    lArray.add((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PM_LinLay2));
    lArray.add((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PM_LinLay3));
    lArray.add((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PM_LinLay4));

    for (LinearLayout l : lArray) {
        l.setOnTouchListener(PracticeFragment.this);
        l.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(0).isEnabled()) {
                    ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(0).performClick();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    rbArray.add((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio0));
    rbArray.add((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio1));
    rbArray.add((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio2));
    rbArray.add((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio3));
    rbArray.add((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio4));

    ivArray.add((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivradio0));
    ivArray.add((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivradio1));
    ivArray.add((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivradio2));
    ivArray.add((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivradio3));
    ivArray.add((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivradio4));


    rootView.findViewById(R.id.bNext).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.bPrevious).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.svMain);

    info.open();
    iRow = Integer.valueOf(info.getEverything(getArguments(), getArguments().getInt("position"), "next"));
    Cursor c = info.getCursor(iRow);
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion))
            .setText((getArguments().getInt("position") + 1) + ") " + c.getString(2));

    explain = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvExplain);
    explain.setText(c.getString(9));
    explain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    correctAnswer = c.getString(8);


    String[] aArray = { c.getString(3), c.getString(4), c.getString(5),
            c.getString(6), c.getString(7) };

    c.close();
    info.close();

    int o = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    for (String s : aArray) {
        LinearLayout l = lArray.get(pos);
        if (s.contentEquals("BLANK")) {
            l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rbArray.get(pos).setText(s);
            rbArray.get(pos).setOnClickListener(null);
            if (o % 2 == 0) {
                l.setBackgroundColor(Consts.colorAlt);
            }
            o++;
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return rootView;
}

}
```

However if I comment out everything but the viewgroup and return rootview - still the same problem.

Comment: add your fragment code also

Comment: @bhaveshN added :) also really grateful for you helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing it fixed the problem!

Comment: I'm having this same problem what do you mean by "subclassing it"

Comment: @AndroidPenguin can you be specific on what code change fixed the issue exactly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

initialize the getAll every time as a new object in getItem()

make your fragment class  static

and create one method in PracticeFragment

```
 static PracticeFragment newInstance(int num) {
        PracticeFragment f = new PracticeFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
```

and change  in adapter

```
     @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PracticeFragment.newInstance(position);
       }
```

Comment: This returns the same error :/

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("position",postition)
Fragment fragment = new PracticeFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;

Comment: get the argument in oncreate method in fragment

Comment: refer this link    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: same problem even when putting it in oncreate :(